# How to cross-validate KMeans with more cluster than classes in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, k-means, cross-validation

I have a dataset containing 2 classes and I'm interested in predicting in which of these classes a new point will fall.

Using KMeans to recognize 2 clusters, and thus assigning to each point of a cluster one of the two classes, results in a bad splitting of the points with both classes in both clusters.
On the other hand, when KMeans is asked for searching 4 clusters, one of them cointains the vast majority of the points of one class, while the other 3 contains the majority of the points of the other one.

My question is, how can I cross-validate my model when it divides the points in 4 classes while I only have 2?

Using this

```
scores = cross_validate(pipe, X, Y, cv=4, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1, scoring=scoring, return_train_score=True)
```

won't work because `Y` only contains two distinct values

Comment: Please **post** your model. In any case, the notion of CV is not really applicable for unsupervised learning.

Comment: Based on your explanation, you need to use a classification technique rather than clustering approach (k-means) to predict the class of new point.  Clustering techniques are used when there is no labeled data and you do not know how many classes are in your data.